# Numpy vs Matlab float to uint8 conversion

Tags: matlab, numpy

As per Matlab's help, `single` values are converted to `uint8` by rounding, e.g.

```
uint8(91.799999)
```

will return us 92.

However, in numpy the following

```
np.uint8(91.799999)
```

will return 91.

Is there a way to match these behaviors in one way or another?

Thanks

Comment: Use `np.ceil` `In [63]: np.ceil(91.799999).astype(np.uint8)
Out[63]: 92
`

Comment: Or, equivalently in MATLAB: `uint8(floor(number))`. @Kasramvd shouldn't you use `np.round()` instead, if MATLAB truly rounds instead of ceils?

Comment: @Adriaan Round is a more general function that depends on the precision which user specifies. In this case it's not clear whether it's ceiling or rounding to upper bound.

Comment: `np.round` uses round-half-to-even, matlab uses round-half-away-from-zero, so that still won't be consistent

Comment: To add to the confusion: Matlab's `sprintf ('%1.1g|', [2.5, -2.5, 3.5, -3.5])` can apply round away from zero (Windows) or run to even (Linux). See [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/38248707#38248707)

Answer (score 4):

There are two things you'd have to be mindful about: the different rounding mode used in np.round vs. MATLAB and the fact that MATLAB casting also clips to the range [0,255] where as numpy overflows/underflows. To make Numpy mimic the uint8 cast in MATLAB:

```
np.uint8(np.clip(91.799999+0.5,0,255))
```

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/integers.html) of Matlab precisely describes how conversion to integers is being done:

> If the number being converted to an integer has a fractional part, MATLAB rounds to the nearest integer. If the fractional part is exactly 0.5, then from the two equally nearby integers, MATLAB chooses the one for which the absolute value is larger in magnitude

With this description you can fairly easy mimic the behavior in python.

Comment: This is all true. Additionally, you'd need to be aware of the clipping behavior casting functions vs. the overflow/underflow behavior of casting in Python for input values outside the range [0,255].

Comment: Range of course differs per type and can be checked [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/user/basics.types.html)